# Getting null instead of text

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get the text from two text fields I have.
But when I try to log the text to the console it always prints nothing, It has the LOG tag of course, but nothing else.
This is my code:

```
class Login extends React.Component {

state =  {
  email : '',
  password: '',
}

handleLogin = () => {
  console.log(this.state.email);
};

render() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.superContainer}>
          <View style={styles.formContainer}>
              <AppTextInput
                placeHolderText="Email@Address.com"
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email: text})}/>
              <AppTextInput
                placeHolderText="Password"
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}/>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <AppButton
              title="LOGIN"
              onPress={this.handleLogin}
              />
          </View>
        </View>

    );
  }
}
```

I searched for an answer, but it seems like it should work. It is written just like in other answers I saw to the same question, and it is written like that on the docs I saw.
What am I doing wrong?

As request, I added an image of the console:
[image]

EDIT: I now tried to change the 'email' in the `this.state` part, when logging it is showing, it seems like the `TextInput` won't get the text on `onChangeText`

Comment: What happens if you switch the state in constructor for this.state?

Comment: @CyberMessiah I am getting an 'unexpected token' error.

Comment: What if you add the values as value={this.state.email}, next to the OnChangeText?

Comment: @CyberMessiah I'm not really sure what you meant, I'm new to React Native, sorry. This is what I wrote after onChangeText: value={this.state.email"}

Comment: Just remove the " after email. Does it show anything at all now?

Comment: @CyberMessiah I'm sorry, the " is not in the code itself, it is a typo here. I now noticed that It seems like the textInput just does not get the text on onChangeText. I tried to set the initial state to "hello" and it prints hello when logging.

Comment: One last try. Replace the onChangeText with the following format:            onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({ email: text})}}>   Notice the additional { before this.setState and } at the end. If that is not working, sorry for the disturbance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import {TextInput} from 'react-native';

class Login extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
  }

handleLogin = () => {
  console.log(this.state.email);
};

render() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.superContainer}>
          <View style={styles.formContainer}>
              <TextInput
                placeHolderText="Email@Address.com"
                onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}/>
              <TextInput
                placeHolderText="Password"
                onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}/>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <AppButton
              title="LOGIN"
              onPress={this.handleLogin}
              />
          </View>
        </View>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but still the same. only see "LOG" and nothing else.

Comment: can you post a screen of what the output is ?

Comment: I edited the first post with the image of the console

Answer (score 0):

I can verify that the following code is working on Snack, I have slightly modified some elements (nothing major) and used the alert, instead of console.log. You may directly paste it onto snack to view the result.

```
import {TextInput} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

class Login extends React.Component {

state =  {
  email : '',
  password: '',
}

handleLogin = () => {
    alert(this.state.password + " " + this.state.email);

};

render() {
    return(
        <View>
          <View>
              <TextInput
                placeHolderText="Email@Address.com"
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email: text})}/>
              <TextInput
                placeHolderText="Password"
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ password: text })} 
              />  
          </View>
          <View >
              <Button
              title="LOGIN"
              onPress={this.handleLogin}
              />
          </View>
        </View>

    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this now, but still the same. I copied your line to avoid a typo, and still the same. it's like the onChangeText does not trigger at all.

Comment: If I were you I would refactor the code with Constructor as the previous answer. Bind this method to the class as    this.handleTextChanged = this.handleTextChanged.bind(this); and then use this  onChangeText={this.handleTextChanged} instead of the one you have. Use as a reference this guide: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19505

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, the problem was that I was using a custom `TextInput` (aka `AppTextInput`) and didn't pass it the `onChangeText`.

Adding to `AppTextInput` `onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText}` fixed the issue.

This is the full render function of `AppTextInput`:

```
render() {
    const { isFocused } = this.state;
    const {onFocus, onBlur, onChangeText} = this.props;
    return (
        <TextInput
            placeholder= {this.props.placeHolderText}
            selectionColor = {COLORS.appOrange}
            underlineColorAndroid={
                isFocused ? COLORS.appOrange : COLORS.appGray
            }

            onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText}
            onFocus = {this.handleFocus}
            onBlur = {this.handleBlur}
            style = {styles.textInput}
        />
    );
}
```